# Application stops when going from one activity to another

Tags: android

while I am using intent to transfer data from one activity to another, whenever I click on submit button, the application gets error

```
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Open();
        }
    });
}
public void  Open(){

    String str1=edt1.getText().toString();
    String str2=edt2.getText().toString();
    Intent intent= new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("Email",str1);
    intent.putExtra("password",str2);
    startActivity(intent);

    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this,"Loading ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();


}
```

```
Second Activity


<code>
Intent intent= getIntent();
         String str1=intent.getStringExtra("Email");
        String str2 =intent.getStringExtra("password");
        email2.setText(str1);
        password2.setText(str2);
<code>
```

when I try to go into another activity, the app stops and exits to main screen

Comment: Add the Stacktrace, please.

Answer (score 2):

this is where you are making mistake in `Open()` function

```
Intent intent= new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting your desired activity to the `intent`

```
 Intent intent= new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("Email",str1);
 intent.putExtra("password",str2);
 startActivity(intent);
```